# How do you activate a link on swipe?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am editing someone else's code who used php (I'm not really comfortable with php) and I need to add in a swipe function so that it is optimized for tablet.

I have an init function like this:

```
 // swipe through pages
  $(function() {
        $.on( 'swipeleft', swipeToNextPage );
        $.on( 'swiperight', swipeToPreviousPage );
    });
```

There is already a header navigation that goes linearly(sp?) through the site so I just want to target them in my swipe functions.

The nav go in this template:

```
<a class="icon-right-dir" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"></a>
```

Can I just fire the icon-right-dir in the swipeToNextPage function?

How would I do that?

```
// swipe left
function swipeToNextPage(){
     // ..uhhhh
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) which fires all the specified event handler of that element.

```
function swipeToNextPage(){
  $('.icon-right-dir').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: cool, i knew it was an easy method but just didn't know the terminology for it. thanks!